# Hortonworks HDP docker how to expose ports publicly

Tags: docker, hortonworks-sandbox

First of all if I am asking a obvious question I apologize in advance.

I am trying to expose Hortonworks HDP docker (version 2.6.5) ports publicly so that the Ambari UI and all the functionality packaged is accessible over the network. I followed the official [documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/tutorials/sandbox-deployment-and-install-guide/3.html) everything is installed locally and running, but I cannot access the UI via the browser using the set ports.

Is there away I can make the docker ports public so it is accessible via the local network?

I am running the docker image on a Ubuntu 18 machine.

[Update]

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                        NAMES
11b583b0deb5        hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:2.6.5   "/usr/sbin/init"    23 seconds ago      Up 22 seconds       22/tcp, 4200/tcp, 8080/tcp   sandbox-hdp
```

Comment: Can you run `docker ps` and share the output?

Comment: @NeoAnderson I have updated my question with the output, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Docker containers are not exposed outside the docker host.
In order do expose port `X` on the host machine and forward traffic to port `Y` inside the container, use the `-p`/`--publish` option when the container is launched.

I haven't downloaded the sources, but I am more than sure that in the `docker-deploy-{HDPversion}.sh` script, you must find a `docker run ...` command, which is launching the `sandbox-hdp` container. Find and add to that line the publish command.

```
-p 9876:8080
```

You should then be able to access your container at `localhost:9876`. You may chose any port you want, that is not in use on the host machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the docker option:
--publish-all                    Publish all exposed ports to random ports